# Cub Cadet XT1 Enduro Series with Kohler 7000 Series engine won't start

Tags: starting, lawnmower, kohler

About 3 years old. This thing just won't start. Video shows current behavior -- when I turn the key the lights flash and the top spins, that's it. Right before this video I replaced the spark plugs and fuel filter.  Before I did that I was getting same behavior but a whiny sound as well.  Any ideas?

- Cub Cadet XT1 Enduro Series
- Engine: KT725-3078

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/q487kt1IwF4

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You need to charge the battery.

Comment: Agree may simply not be spinning enough to start. Should be able to crank and crank. Also my z-turn battery was gone at 3 years and needed replacing. Was a tad similar to what you have. See if you can jump it to get it started

Comment: The battery may be dead, unable to power the starter up to crank the engine. If the engine flooded, excessive fuel may prevent the engine from turning. Removing both spark plugs and cranking the engine can expel raw fuel then replacing (dried if wet) plugs for another startup, perhaps jump starting with a car battery.  Usually with plugs removed, the engine will spin up quickly without compression interference.